# In rails 3 how do you have text and image in link_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, link-to

I want a link with text and an image.
Before rails 3 internet tells me that you must do :

```
<%= link_to "my text"+image_tag("image.jpg"), {:controller=>:billets}, :class => 'link_to_blog'%>
```

However in rails 3 i have the code of the image displayerd in my web page instead of the image. Seems now, it escape the html code.

How can i do a link_to with text and image in rails 3?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<%= link_to ("my text"+image_tag("image.jpg")).html_safe, {:controller=>:billets}, :class => 'link_to_blog'%>
```

Or

```
<%= link_to {:controller => :billets}, :class => 'link_to_blog' do %>
  My text
  <%= image_tag "image.jpg" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I guess it should be link_to ({:controller => :billets}, :class => 'link_to_blog') do